# Adding Multiple Labels in a View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uilabel

I want to add as many labels as objects in my array. but how to align them??.i want one below the other,and id the page is done it should start in the next column.but with the code i tried its overriding the other.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    array = [[ NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aaa",@"bbb",@"ccc",@"ddd",nil];
    for( int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
    {
        NSString *theText = [array lastObject];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        label.text = theText;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        label.frame = CGRectMake(0, label.frame.origin.y + label.frame.size.height, size.width + 20, size.height + 20);
        [self.view addSubview:label];
    }
}
```

Comment: you're adding last object always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this code..

```
array = [[ NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aaa",@"bbb",@"ccc",@"ddd",nil];
UILabel *label;
int y =10;
for( int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{
    NSString *theText = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    label.text = theText;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   label.frame = CGRectMake(0, y + label.frame.size.height, size.width + 20,   size.height + 20);
[self.view addSubview:label];
    y = y +label.frame.size.height+5;
}
```

Comment: this is working if there are more objects and view is full how to put next objects in another column

Comment: Add the UILabel objects i.e. label to the UIScrollView. And then make  [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, y)];

Answer (score 0):

You are always taking last Object in the loop. Instead you should take object from proper index.

```
int y = 10;
for( int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{
    //NSString *theText = [array lastObject]; Wrong One
    NSString *theText = [array objectAtIndex:i]; //Correct One
    ...
    ...
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, size.width + 20,   size.height);
    y += size.height + 5;

}
```

Also, you need to manage origin.y properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    float originFromY = 0;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    array = [[ NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aaa",@"bbb",@"ccc",@"ddd",nil];
    for( int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
    {
         NSString *theText = [array lastObject];
         UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
         label.text = theText;
          label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        label.frame = CGRectMake(0, originFromY, 50,40);
       [self.view addSubview:label];
       originFromY += 60;
    }
 }
```

may this will help you

Answer (score 0):

your modified code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
array = [[ NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aaa",@"bbb",@"ccc",@"ddd",nil];
int y = 0;
for( int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{
    NSString *theText = [array lastObject];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    label.text = theText;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, size.width + 20, size.height + 20);
    y += size.height + 20;
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  array = [[ NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aaa",@"bbb",@"ccc",@"ddd",nil];
  for( int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
  {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    label.text = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    label.frame = CGRectMake(10, (i*30)+10, 100, 30); // here height is 30 and width is 100;
    [self.view addSubview:label];
   }
  }
```